# Fast join for a lot of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have around 480 dataframes. Each dataframe is organised as follows:

1. Each dataframe has *around* 600*512 rows
2. Each dataframe has 6 relevant columns, whose one (timestamp) is unique and can be used as index.
3. Each dataframe may miss some rows (i.e., some timestamps), so concatenating them is not possible.
4. Before performing the concatenation, I need to concatenate two dataframe index-wise (to extend the timestamps)

My current solution is to incrementally build a dataframe:

```py
# Function to concat index wise the dataframes
def get_joint_dataframe(it, trial_path):
    train_path = os.path.join(trial_path, "train_results_iteration_{0}.csv".format(it)) # 1st dataframe
    test_path = os.path.join(trial_path, "results_iteration_{0}.csv".format(it)) # 2st dataframe

    train_df = pd.read_csv(train_path)
    test_df = pd.read_csv(test_path)

    train_df = pd.concat([train_df, test_df], axis=0, ignore_index=True)# safe to do as I know index sets are disjoint
    train_df = train_df.sort_values(by = 'timestamp').reset_index(drop=True)

    return train_df

# Build incremental dataframe
def get_action_df_speedup(trials):

    df_action_all = None # Incremental dataframe
    policy_count = 0

    for trial in trials:
        for it in range(1, 11):
            df_action = get_joint_dataframe(it, trial)[['timestamp', 'day', 'action']] # In the real case there are 3 additional columns
            df_action = df_action.rename(columns={'action':'policy_{0}'.format(policy_count)})

            columns_to_join = ['policy_{0}'.format(policy_count)] # I do not need to join 'day', just use the one of the first dataframe

            df_action.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)

            if df_action_all is None:
                df_action_all = df_action
            else:
                df_action_all = df_action_all.join(df_action[columns_to_join], how="inner")
            
            policy_count += 1
        
    df_action_all.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=False)   
    return df_action_all
```

I actually perform a `join` as in other overflow posts I saw that it tends to be faster than `merge` when using the column as index. However, this code takes WAY too much time (for 20 dataframes, about 40 seconds, so 2 hours and half for the whole dataset).

Is there a way to speedup this setup?

EDIT: I am sorry for not posting an example of csv

```py
        timestamp   day   action    reward      Q          Q1         Q2          Q0
0   2.017010e+12    2017/01/03  0.0 0.0 0.008301    0.008301    -1.111009   -0.172822
1   2.017010e+12    2017/01/03  0.0 0.0 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
2   2.017010e+12    2017/01/03  0.0 0.0 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
3   2.017010e+12    2017/01/03  0.0 0.0 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
4   2.017010e+12    2017/01/03  0.0 0.0 0.000000    0.000000    0.000000    0.000000
```

**Note timestamps are unique, even if it does not seem so**. Moreover, in a previous version I thought about concatenating all dfs via a list, but I needed to rename all columns and also, in principle, I CANNOT concatenate dfs straight away.

EDIT 2: I developed a solution which in principle takes less time (around 120, which is definitely better)

```py
# Get action dataframe, along with a translator to get the path of a trial
def get_dfs_speedup(trials):

    # Logic
    def manage_df(iteration, trial, policy_count, translator, columns_Q, columns_pol):
        action_df = get_joint_dataframe(iteration, trial)[['timestamp', 'day', 'action', 'Q0', 'Q1', 'Q2']]
        translator['policy_{0}'.format(policy_count[0])] = (trial, iteration)
        dict_transl_action = {'action':'policy_{0}'.format(policy_count[0])}
        dict_transl_Q = {'Q{0}'.format(i):'policy_{1}_Q{0}'.format(i, policy_count[0]) for i in range(3)}
        action_df = action_df.rename(columns={'action':'policy_{0}'.format(policy_count[0])})
        action_df = action_df.rename(columns={'Q{0}'.format(i):'policy_{1}_Q{0}'.format(i, policy_count[0]) for i in range(3)})
        action_df.set_index('timestamp', inplace=True)
        # Update translator
        # Collect indexes which will be used to index dataframe
        columns_Q.extend(list(dict_transl_Q.values()))
        columns_pol.extend(list(dict_transl_action.values()))
        # We now add the df to list
        columns_to_join = list(dict_transl_action.values())
        columns_to_join.extend(list(dict_transl_Q.values()))
        if policy_count[0] == 0:
            columns_to_join.append('day')

        policy_count[0] += 1

        print("Done policy: {0}".format(policy_count[0]))
        return action_df[columns_to_join]
    
    translator = {}
    columns_Q = ['day']
    columns_pol = ['day']
    policy_count = [0]

    all_dfs = [manage_df(iteration, trial, policy_count, translator, columns_Q, columns_pol) for iteration, trial in it.product(list(range(1, 11)), trials)]
    
    # Now we simply concatenate columns wise
    all_dfs = pd.concat(all_dfs, axis=1, ignore_index=False, join='inner')
    # We want both action and q dfs, with translator
    #print(columns_Q, all_dfs.columns)
    Q_df = all_dfs[columns_Q]
    actions_df = all_dfs[columns_pol]
    # We reset_index to get back our timestamp
    Q_df.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
    actions_df.reset_index(drop=False, inplace=True)
    # End
    return Q_df, actions_df, translator
```

Comment: **Don't loop. Python loops are evil**. Make a list/tuple `my_dfs` of DataFrames to join and use `pd.concat(my_dfs)`

Comment: Python loops are evil, damm.

Comment: If you post code that generates test data to be joined, then contributors can more readily help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I am sorry, I fixed my question accordingly. Also, in a previous version I grouped all csv, but I cannot simply concat them. Does concat take into consideration the fact that different dataframes may have different indexes? Moreover, I am just really unsure about how I should open all dataframe all at once without a loop... maybe a comprehension?

Comment: Loading the dataframes isn't where the issue with loops come in, the loops are evil comment is more about when you're actually processing dataframes. Concat should work for your situation and if you wanted to you could do it in 2 lines. Eg: dataframes=['df1.csv', 'df2.csv'] and then pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file) for file in dataframes])

Comment: In the end I went for the comprehension way... I received a decent speedup.